# Plotting No-Fermi scaling function

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

Given the function below

[image]

How can one plot with `x` in the horizontal and `g(x)` in the vertical axis for different values of `x`? Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

"13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)"

ClearAll["Global`*"]

g[x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[1/((1 - t)^(2/3) + t^(2/3) + x), {t, 0, 1},
   MaxRecursion -> 100,
   WorkingPrecision -> 15];

Plot[g[x], {x, -2, 2},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 WorkingPrecision -> 17]
```

[image]